# Automatically and continuously copy files of a certain extension created in source folder and not present in output with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that creates .jpegs in a folder and deletes them after a very short time. I'd like to automatically copy those files to another folder as they are created and before they are deleted. I tried using robocopy but couldn't manage. How can I do this with Python?

Comment: Please edit (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71734546/edit) your code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is this an independent program or one you can insert your code into? If you are racing against another program and the lifetime of these files is very short  you will likely end up with file access errors that will kill one or both programs. Otherwise, this is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script analyse your dir and move file if finded:

```
import os

def main():
    #search for file in your dir
    for file in os.listdir('path/to/dir'):
        if file.endswith('.jpegs'):
            #if extension = ".jpegs" -> move your file
            os.replace("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #infinite loop
    while True:
        main()
```

and this other is for copy file:

```
import os
import shutil

def main():
    #search for file in your dir
    for file in os.listdir('path/to/dir'):
        #if extension = ".jpegs"
        if file.endswith('.jpegs'):
            #source file
            src = f'path/to/dir/{file}'
            #destination
            dest = f'path/to/new/destination/for/{file}'
            #if it does not exist
            if not os.path.isfile(dest):
                #copy file
                shutil.copyfile(src, dest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #infinite loop
    while True:
        main()
```

`CTRL+C` in your terminal for end script

Comment: Is there a version which copies instead?

Comment: No this version move your file. if you want to copy file you can use shutil like "import shutil shutil.copyfile(src, dest). But if you do that you need a condition not to copy an existing file

Comment: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: make chmod on your dirs. see: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied/#:~:text=The%20PermissionError%3A%20%5Berrno%2013%5D%20permission%20denied%20error%20occurs%20when,group%20can%20access%20the%20file.